# NV toolkit extensions include file location - Linux vs Windows

Tags: cuda, include-path, nvtx

On Linux, if you have `/path/to/cuda-10.0/include` in your include path, you can `#include <nvToolsExt.h>`, and life is good. However, a collaborator using Windows has just told me that (with CUDA 10), the nvtx-related include files are in a subdirectory of the general CUDA include directory, named `nvtx3`.

I don't use Windows, but I can't believe he got it wrong, so:

- How come there's a different include directory structure?
- Why has this happened with CUDA 10 as opposed to previous versions?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the the [How do I use NVTX in my code?](https://github.com/NVIDIA/NVTX#how-do-i-use-nvtx-in-my-code) section of the README in the NVTX repository:

> *NOTE:* Older versions of NVTX did require linking against a dynamic library. NVTX version 3 provides the same API, but removes the need to link with any library. Ensure you are including NVTX v3 by using the `nvtx3` directory as a prefix in your #includes: [...]

Another section of interest is [Get NVTX with the CUDA Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/NVTX#get-nvtx-with-the-cuda-toolkit):

> The CUDA toolkit provides NVTX v3. Note that the toolkit may also include older versions for backwards compatibility, so be sure to use version 3 (the `nvtx3` subdirectory of headers) for best performance, convenience, and support. Use `#include <nvtx3/nvToolsExt.h>` instead of `#include <nvToolsExt.h>` to ensure code is including v3!

It seems like the existence of the `nvtx3` subdirectory is not Windows-specific. Maybe the Windows version of the CUDA toolkit your colleague was using did not include those *older versions for backwards compatibility* or he ignored them.